# Content moves upward when I change the display of a div

Tags: html, css

As a novice web developer I've been trying to build myself a personal webpage from scratch. However I've encountered a problem.

[Here's my webpage](https://deepburner.github.io), it looks ok but when you click any of the links on the left side, and turn a # to display:block from display:none you can see the "bleeding" on the bottom.

I have no idea why this happens, so I'm linking [my repo](https://github.com/DeepBurner/deepburner.github.io) which contains the html and the css for the page.

Comment: Hi, please include an isolated snippet of the relevant code in your post, rather than linking to an off-site webpage.

Comment: That's the thing, I have no idea where's the problem

Comment: There are no links on the right side and there is no "bleeding" in Chrome - Oh and welcome to GeoCities

Comment: Hi, edit your question adding the entire html code in order to see what's happening.

Comment: @Waylander In that case, port your site's HTML and CSS to https://www.jsfiddle.net and then start removing CSS line by line. We know, for example, that animated background probably isn't causing your problem.

Comment: @jsanchezs - no - he needs to add enough to show the issue.

Comment: The problem is related to your `padding-top: 100px` that you've given your #links

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a simple CSS in your Canvas Tag

```
style="position:fixed"
```

and its Done

Comment: `<canvas id="canv" style="position:fixed;"></canvas>`

DID you add exactly like this?

Comment: Turns out I misplaced a quote, tried it again and it works! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question you want to remove the green band at the bottom of the page.

It comes from your background-color:

```
body {
    /* background-color: #A7DBD8; */
}
```

Juste remove it and it's ok ;)

Remy

Comment: It's definitely less noticeable, but the page still moves upward, just now the strip is black D:

Answer (score 0):

Changing the style on the canvas element from

```
display: inline-block;
```

to

```
display: block;
```

fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the :

```
<div class="footer">
```

from the index.html because you're not using it

Answer (score 0):

Your panes are a fixed width and height: 620px, 500px respectively. If you add `padding-top: 100px` to a pane (as you did with `#links` div), it will increase your height to 600px and push things down.

The quick fix is to, instead of adding `padding-top: 100px` to your `#links` div, add it to the first paragraph in your `#links` div.

```
#links p:first-child {
      padding-top: 100px;
}
```